# How to figure rafter lengths on a lean-to to shed roof?

Tags: framing, roof

I am building a 12x16 lean-to shed and I am at the point where I need to make my rafters. I plan on using 14' metal panels for the roof. The shed is 12' wide and my one wall is 12' high and the other is 10' high. I am trying to figure out my length for the rafters. I have 1x6x16 for the rafters. I plan on using 1x6 for the fascia and would like it to be offset 1/4" inward from each end of the roofing panel. I expected to get 1' overhang on both ends. My thoughts were that I could take 14'(12"/1') = 168" and reduce by 2 1/2" to obtain 165.5". When I tried this, I do not get the 12" over hang I was expecting. What am I missing? Is using the 14' panels not going to give me the 1' on each end that I was expecting? Thanks.

Comment: 1x6x16 rafters? Is that a typo?

Comment: Measure your roof panel length. Subtract 2(1/4"+ 3/4") = 2", and that's your rafter length, no?

Comment: The slope will be ~12.69ft.  a^2 + b^2 = c^2.  Either get longer panels or shorten expected over hang.

Comment: @crip659, I think that 2-1/2" was intended to correct for the slope. I computed the sloped length over the 12' as 12'-2" (a=12', b=2'). Never mind. The 2-1/2" was for the fascia thickness and sought overhang.

Comment: There are all sorts of rafter length calculators available for free on the web. That's what I used to calculate the length of rafter I needed for my new shop...

Answer (score 0):

Don't assume that your roof panels are exactly 14'-0". Measure the roof panel length. Calling the overall length L and assuming that the 1×6 has 3/4" thickness, then L - 2(1/4" + 3/4") = L - 2" is your rafter length. Cut the rafter ends at arcsin(2/12) = 10° if you want your fascia plumb. The top edge should be the L - 2" dimension if you cut the ends at 10°.

You neglected the length of the *sloped* roof. That's why your overhang is less than 12". The sloped length over the 12' long opening that shifts elevation by 2' is sqrt((12')^2 + (2')^2) = 12.17' = 12'-2".

Comment: popham, Thanks for the response. You are correct. I did not figure in the slope. As for the 1x6 I was planning on using that for my fascia board. I am using 2x6 for my rafter.